# How to build Android project from the command line on Windows

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, build

I've got an older Android project (still using Eclipse) that I need to build from the command line.  It just builds a library (.jar file), not an application (.apk file).  I installed ANT, but since there's no build.xml file it doesn't do anything.

All the examples I've found say to use the "android" command to generate build configurations, but I do not have the "android" command on my PC and searching on "download android command" didn't product any useful results.

Where does one get the "android" command?  Do I actually need it in my case, or will a simple generic build.xml file of some kind do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple but not exactly easy to find (IMHO), thus this posting.

By default, the Android SDK adds its "platform-tools" sub-directory to your path but the "android" command is in the "tools" sub-directory.  So one just needs to manually edit the PC's PATH environment variable to add the "tools" directory.